# What is the definition of the Complete Gamma Function?

Tags: gamma-function, bernoulli-numbers

this topic is kind of confusing me a lot. I am working with a text book that defined the Complete Gamma Function as follows:

$$\ln\Gamma(x) = \ln\sqrt 2\pi-x+(x-\frac{1}{2})\ln x +\frac{B_1}{1\cdot2}\frac{1}{x}+\frac{B_2}{3\cdot4}\frac{1}{x^3}+\frac{B_3}{5\cdot6}\frac{1}{x^5}+\frac{B_4}{7\cdot8}\frac{1}{x^7}+\frac{B_1}{9\cdot10}\frac{1}{x^9}+... $$

with B<sub>j</sub> as the Bernoullian numbers

$$ B_1 = \frac{1}{6}; B_2 = \frac{1}{30};B_3 = \frac{1}{42};B_4 = \frac{1}{30};B_5 = \frac{5}{66}$$

This truncates the Gamma function according to the textbook as

$$ \ln\Gamma(x) = \ln\sqrt 2\pi-x+(x-\frac{1}{2})\ln x +\frac{1}{x}(\frac{1}{12}-\frac{1}{x^2}(\frac{1}{360}-\frac{1}{x^2}(\frac{1}{1260}-\frac{1}{x^2}(\frac{1}{1680}-\frac{1}{x^2}\frac{1}{1188})))) $$

I found this definition here: http://research.dnv.com/hci/ocean/bk/c/a26/sa.htm

Now, how is this Gamma function related to the Gamma function which is usually defined as

$$\Gamma(z) = \int_0^\infty x^{z-1} e^{-x}\,{\rm d}x $$

Please dont be too harsh, I'm an engineer

Comment: Your series for $\log \Gamma(x)$ doesn't converge, the Bernouilli numbers grow way too fast. It is only an asymptotic approximation (when truncating the series). There are two definitions for $\log \Gamma(x)$, one from your integral, the other from the Weierstrass product for $\Gamma(x)$.  Relating the two isn't trivial.

Comment: @reuns thanks for that answer. Would you, by any chance, have an idea why they used this weird definition in the book?

Comment: MathWorld gives the identity $\text{log$\Gamma$}(z)=\frac{1}{2} \log(2 \pi)-z+\left(z-\frac{1}{2}\right) \log(z)+\frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{k=2}^\infty \frac{(k-1)\, \zeta(k,z+1)}{k\, (k+1)}$ which is valid for $\Re(z)>0$ (see https://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/LogGamma/06/04/) so it appears $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{B_n}{(2 n-1) 2 n}\, z^{-(2 n-1)}$ is an approximation of $\frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{k=2}^\infty \frac{(k-1)\, \zeta(k,z+1)}{k\, (k+1)}$.

Comment: When you say: "This renders as" this is false, you have truncated the series too harshly. As mentioned by others the series does not even converge

Comment: @FShrike you are correct, I edited that phrase to avoid confusing people reading this in the future